# Tkinter window backend coding

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import pyupbit
from tkinter import *

class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, window):
        Frame.__init__(self, window)

        self.window = window

        self.price = Label(self.window, text='hello')
        self.price.place(x=20,y=20)

        self.get_price()

    def get_price(self):
        self.after(100, self.get_price)

        price = pyupbit.get_current_price('KRW-BTC')
        self.price.configure(text=price)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('300x300')
    Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to show bitcoin price every ms. I guess, because of api delay, the window looks have lags. I want to get the price in the backend and show it on frontend. How can I ? Can I get examples?

Comment: No, you are trying to show the bitcoin price every 100ms.

Comment: Try putting `pyupbit.get_current_price('KRW-BTC')` in another thread

Comment: Is there any thread example?

Comment: If the problem is latency in the fetch, using threads won't do a thing.  If it takes 300ms to fetch the price, you cannot possibly update faster than 300ms.  And, of course, you can't update the UI in a secondary thread.

Comment: You also need to place the `after` method after `self.price.configure(text=price)`

Comment: @JacksonPro why? It doesn't matter

Comment: @TimRoberts yes but the window feels laggy because it can update itself every 400 ms. If you move the code that takes a lot of time in another thread, it will free up the tkinter loop.

Comment: @TheLizzard It does matter. If you place it before updating anything using `after ` is pretty useless.

Comment: @JacksonPro No. After adds the function to be called in the queue of events. Therefore, it will be executed when the function ends and the code execution is given back to `root.mainloop()`. From that it follows that it doesn't matter if you update the label first or push the `get_price` function on the queue with events.

Comment: @TheLizzard it matters, in this case. firstly because `pyupbit.get_current_price('KRW-BTC')` takes a long time to execute. 100ms doesn't seem to be enough for the function to complete execution and `after` method gives a call back every 100ms. Hence the main loop is busy executing this function and no other events can happen, which is also why the GUI does't appear. Changing the time to say something greater than 100 ms can work. but by placing `after` at the end of the function you can be sure that the timer starts after all the heavy process is completed.

Comment: @TheLizzard you will also have a more responsive GUI when compared to placing before. Though as you have already answered its better to execute the processes that take too much time in another thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import pyupbit
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, window):
        super().__init__(window)

        self.window = window
        self.price = 0

        self.price_label = Label(self.window, text='hello')
        self.price_label.place(x=20,y=20)

        thread = Thread(target=self.get_price_loop, daemon=True)
        thread.start()

        self.show_price()

    def show_price(self):
        self.price_label.configure(text=self.price)
        self.after(30, self.show_price)

    def get_price_loop(self):
        while True:
            self.price = pyupbit.get_current_price('KRW-BTC')
            # Here you can add a bit of delay using `time.sleep(0.1)`

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('300x300')
    Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I has 2 loops. The tkinter loop displays whatever is in the `self.price` variable and the `while True` loop in the other thread updates that value by using `self.price = pyupbit.get_current_price('KRW-BTC')`.

Comment: @Robinshim make sure that you **don't** have any tkinter stuff in the other thread. Tcl will crash and you will get a headache trying to debug it :D

Comment: Can I ask you why?

Comment: @Robinshim tcl doesn't like it (and crashes) if you use tkinter object from a thread that isn't the thread where you created the `tk.Tk()`. It is a quirk of tcl.

Comment: Than how can I solve the problem I have without using it?

Comment: @Robinshim You can exchange variables (that aren't part of tkinter) between threads without any problems (assuming they are thread safe). In my solution the second thread just updates `self.price` while the main (tkinter) thread updates the label. The only variable exchanged between the threads is `self.price` which is fine